# Null Pointer while Traversing through Binary Tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I was doing an assignment in which I'm supposed to create a binary tree and define given functions from its abstract superclass (AbstractBinaryTree.java). 
While working on a function called `getNumbers()` which is basically going to traverse through the whole tree whilst adding values from each node to an array list which it returns. There seems to be a null pointer in one of my if statements.

AbstractBinaryTree.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class AbstractBinaryTree
{
    protected Node  root;
    protected int   sizeOfTree;

    public AbstractBinaryTree()
    {
        root = null;
        sizeOfTree = 0;
    }

    public int size(){ return sizeOfTree; }

    /** compute the depth of a node */
    public abstract int depth(Node node);

    /** Check if a number is in the tree or not */
    public abstract boolean find(Integer i);

    /** Create a list of all the numbers in the tree. */
    /*  If a number appears N times in the tree then this */
    /*  number should appear N times in the returned list */
    public abstract ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers();


    /** Adds a leaf to the tree with number specifed by input.  */
    public abstract void addLeaf(Integer i);

    /** Removes "some" leaf from the tree.       */
    /*  If the tree is empty should return null  */
    public abstract Node removeLeaf();



    // these methods are only needed if you wish
    // use the TreeGUI visualization program
    public int getheight(Node n){
        if( n == null) return 0;
        return 1 +  Math.max(
        getheight(n.getLeft()) ,  getheight(n.getRight())
        );
    }

    public int height(){ return getheight(root); }



}
```

Node.java File.

```
public class Node{
    protected Integer data;
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node(Integer data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }

    public Node(Integer data, Node left, Node right){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Integer getData(){ return this.data; }
    public Node    getLeft(){ return this.left; }
    public Node    getRight(){ return this.right; }

    public void setLeft(Node left){ this.left = left; }
    public void setRight(Node right){ this.right = right; }
    public void setData(Integer data){ this.data = data; }
}
```

BinaryTree.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
// Student Name:     Adrian Robertson
// Student Number:   101020295
//
// References:       Collier,  R.  "Lectures  Notes  for  COMP1406C-        Introduction  to  Computer  Science  II"  [PDF  documents]. Retrieved from cuLearn: https://www.carleton.ca/culearn/(Winter2016).//
// References:         http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/deleting-a-node-from-a-binary-search-tree
//                       http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal
//                    http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal- without-recursion-and-without-stack/
public class BinaryTree extends AbstractBinaryTree
{
    protected Node root = new Node(12);

    public static BinaryTree create()
    {
        BinaryTree tempTree = new BinaryTree();
        //creating all the nodes
        Node temp10 = new Node(10);
        Node temp40 = new Node(40);
        Node temp30 = new Node(30);
        Node temp29 = new Node(29);
        Node temp51 = new Node(51);
        Node temp61 = new Node(61);
        Node temp72 = new Node(72);
        Node temp31 = new Node(31);
        Node temp32 = new Node(32);
        Node temp42 = new Node(42);
        Node temp34 = new Node(34);
        Node temp2 = new Node(2);
        Node temp61x2 = new Node(61);
        Node temp66 = new Node(66);
        Node temp3 = new Node(3);
        Node temp73 = new Node(73);
        Node temp74 = new Node(74);
        Node temp5 = new Node(5);
        //setting up the tree
        if (tempTree.root.getData() == null)
        {
            tempTree.root.setData(12);
            tempTree.root.setLeft(temp10);
            tempTree.root.setRight(temp40);
        }
        temp10.setLeft(temp30);
        temp30.setRight(temp29);
        temp29.setRight(temp51);
        temp51.setLeft(temp61);
        temp51.setRight(temp72);
        temp40.setLeft(temp31);
        temp31.setLeft(temp42);
        temp31.setRight(temp34);
        temp34.setLeft(temp61x2);
        temp61x2.setLeft(temp66);
        temp61x2.setRight(temp73);
        temp40.setRight(temp32);
        temp32.setRight(temp2);
        temp2.setLeft(temp3);
        temp3.setRight(temp74);
        temp74.setLeft(temp5);
        return tempTree;
    }
    public int depth(Node node)
    {
        Node current = this.root;
        int counter = 1;
        while(node != current)
        {
            if (node.getData() > current.getData())
            current = current.getRight();
            if (node.getData() < current.getData())
            current = current.getLeft();
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public boolean find(Integer i)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        Node current = this.root;
        if (i == current.getData())
        found = true;
        while (i != current.getData())
        {
            if (i > current.getData())
            current = current.getRight();
            if (i < current.getData())
            current = current.getLeft();
            if (i == current.getData())
            found = true;
        }
        return found;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Node current = this.root;
        Node Pre = new Node(null);
        while (current.getData() != null )
        {
            if (current.getLeft().getData() == null) 
            {
                temp.add(current.getData());
                current = current.getRight();
            }
            else
            {
                /* Find the inorder predecessor of current */
                Pre = current.getLeft();
                while(Pre.getRight() != null && Pre.getRight() != current)
                Pre = Pre.getRight();

                /* Make current as right child of its inorder predecessor */
                if (Pre.getRight() == null)
                {
                    Pre.setRight(current);
                    current = current.getLeft();

                }
                /* Revert the changes made in if part to restore the original tree i.e., fix the right child of predecssor */
                else
                {
                    Pre.setRight(null);
                    temp.add(current.getData());
                    current = current.getRight();
                }/* End of if condition Pre.right == NULL */
            }/* End of if condition current.left == NULL*/

        }/*End of while */
        Collections.sort(temp);
        return temp;

    }
    public void addLeaf(Integer i)
    {
        insert(this.root, i);

    }
    public static void insert(Node node, int value) //insert a node Based on provided argument where node is the root of tree
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            Node first = new Node(value);
            node = first;
        }
        else if (value < node.getData())
        {
            if (node.left != null)
            {
                insert(node.left, value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(" > Inserted " + value + " to left  of node " + node.getData());
                Node newNode = new Node(value);
                node.left = newNode;
            }
        }
        else if (value > node.getData())
        {
            if (node.right != null)
            {
                insert(node.right, value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(" > Inserted " + value + " to right of node " + node.getData());
                Node newNode = new Node(value);
                node.right = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
    public Node removeLeaf()
    {
        Node tempA = new Node(61);  //create a new node with that value
        deleteNodeBST(this.root, 61); //delete the node containing that leaf value
        return tempA; //return the copy of that node
    }
    //delete given node with given value
    public boolean deleteNodeBST(Node node, int data) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = this.getNumbers();
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (node.getData() == data) {

            if ((node.getLeft() == null) && (node.getRight() == null)) {
                // leaf node
                node = null;
                return true;
            }

            if ((node.getLeft() != null) && (node.getRight() != null)) {
                // node with two children
                node.setData(temp.get(0));
                return true;
            }

            // either left child or right child
            if (node.getLeft() != null) {
                this.root.setLeft(node.getLeft());
                node = null;
                return true;
            }

            if (node.getRight() != null) {
                this.root.setRight(node.getRight());
                node = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        this.root = node;
        if (node.getData() > data) {
            return deleteNodeBST(node.getLeft(), data);
            } else {
            return deleteNodeBST(node.getRight(), data);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BinaryTree myTree = new BinaryTree();
        myTree.create();
        System.out.println(myTree.getNumbers());
    }
}
```

The create function creates a binary tree and returns that binary tree. This is the predefined binary tree that I was supposed to create according to assignment guidelines. I understand that the tree values are not organised properly as they would be in a proper binary tree. Is that was causes the null pointer during traversal? Cause the traversal is taylored to work for a proper Binary tree.

Comment: please add error logs

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `getNumbers - method` accordingly,

> You need to put right checks before work with reference type.

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Node current = this.root;
        Node Pre = new Node(null);
        while (current != null && current.getData() != null ) // Fix here... Add : current != null
        {
            if (current.getLeft() != null && current.getLeft().getData() == null) // Fix here... Add : current.getLeft() != null
            {
                temp.add(current.getData());
                current = current.getRight();
            }
            else
            {

                /* Find the inorder predecessor of current */
                Pre = current.getLeft();
                while(Pre != null  && Pre.getRight() != null && Pre.getRight() != current)  // Fix here... Add : Pre != null 
                Pre = Pre.getRight();

                /* Make current as right child of its inorder predecessor */
                if (Pre != null  && Pre.getRight() == null)  // Fix here... Add : Pre != null 
                {
                    Pre.setRight(current);
                    current = current.getLeft();

                }
                /* Revert the changes made in if part to restore the original tree i.e., fix the right child of predecssor */
                else
                {
                    if(Pre != null){ // Fix here... Add : Pre != null 
                         Pre.setRight(null);
                    }

                    temp.add(current.getData());
                    current = current.getRight();
                }/* End of if condition Pre.right == NULL */
            }/* End of if condition current.left == NULL*/

        }/*End of while */
        Collections.sort(temp);
        return temp;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In class BinaryTree, you initialize the left and right of your root node only if the haven't data. But the root node is create with data...

You should invert the condition in :

```
//setting up the tree
if (tempTree.root.getData() == null)
```

And add a test in getNumbers() :

```
 if (current.getLeft() == null || current.getLeft().getData() == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `BinaryTree` class, `getNumbers()` method and `while` loop. Maybe your problem is here:

```
if (current.getLeft().getData() == null) {
    temp.add(current.getData());
    current = current.getRight();
}
```

When you call `current.getLeft()`, it will return `null` when the `left` Node is `null`. And then, you call `getData()` it will throw a `NullPointerException`. If you're not sure that it always not null check it before you call any methods of it. Example you can change the if statement to:

```
if (current.getLeft() != null && current.getLeft().getData() == null) {
    temp.add(current.getData());
    current = current.getRight();
}
```

Or:

```
Node left = current.getLeft();
if (left == null) {
    //TODO something here
} else if (left.getData() == null) {
    temp.add(current.getData());
    current = current.getRight();
}
```

Comment: Alright I see, if the node doesnt exist then there are no attributes to access.